# What is the correlation between grit and Big 5 conscientiousness?

Tags: personality

There's been quite a bit of talk about "grit", lately. And the first response of many was to ponder whether it is different from big 5 conscientiousness.

Thus, I was wondering what the correlation is between "grit" and Big 5 conscientiousness?

Answer (score 3):

There is some discussion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grit_(personality_trait)#Grit_and_personality_measures)

> A meta-analysis [by Crede et al] found that the grit was functionally a measure of conscientiousness

A study by Mayer and Skimmyhorn (2017) using two large military cadet samples (i.e., samples of approximately 1000 in each) obtained measures of Grit (12 item measure, Duckworth, et al 2007) and IPIP 20 item conscientiousness. They obtained correlations between conscientiousness and grit of .75 and .74 in the two samples. The reliability of conscientiousness was close around .90 for conscientiousness and .80 for grit. Thus, the correlations suggest that almost all of the meaningful individual differences are shared across the two scales.
[image: correlations between grit and conscientiousness]

#### References

Mayer, J. D., & Skimmyhorn, W. (2017). Personality attributes that predict cadet performance at West Point. Journal of Research in Personality, 66, 14-26.

Crede, Marcus; Tynan, Michael; Harms, Peter. "Much Ado About Grit: A Meta-Analytic Synthesis of the Grit Literature.". Journal of Personality and Social Psychology. doi:10.1037/pspp0000102. PMID 27845531